# Line integral and parametrization

Tags: vector-analysis

A vector field $F= (\sin y) i + x(1+\cos y)j$.  Evaluate the line integral over the cirxular path $x^2+y^2=a^2,z=0$?
Answer: $\pi a^2$. 
I know how to do it using parametric form of circle but i really want to know how to do it without parametrization,  since it doesn't matter therefore answer should be same with both methods.  I am getting integrals of $\sin (\cos u),\tan u\cos(\sin u)$ without using parametrization, and these integrals involve some $H$ and $J$ as i saw how to integrate them.  But my actual problem is please someone verify without  using parametrization you are getting $\pi a^2$.

Comment: _"with both methods"_ Can you specify what (other) method you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

> but i really want to know how to do it without parametrization

I assume you mean by using a theorem to avoid having to compute the line integral directly (via a parametrization of the circle). Since the path is closed, you can apply [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem).

With the notation from that page, you have $L=\sin y$ and $M = x\left( 1+\cos y\right)$ so:
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}
= \frac{\partial \left( x\left( 1+\cos y\right) \right)}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial \left( \sin y \right)}{\partial y}
= 1+\cos y - \cos y = 1$$
This makes the calculations very easy; integrating over the disc $D$ bounded by the path (circle $C$):
$$\int_C \vec F \cdot \mbox{d} \vec r = \iint_D \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\right) \,\mbox{d}x\,\mbox{d}y = \iint_D 1 \,\mbox{d}x\,\mbox{d}y = \mbox{Area}(D)=\pi a^2$$

Comment: No , i doesn't mean by using green's theorem.  I meant to say that by dividing the circle into two halves and writing y=(1-x^2)^1/2 for upper half of circle and similarly for lower half and then integrating by expressing x in terms of y or vice-versa

Comment: Why would you do that? Then you parametrize again, with $x$ as the parameter.

Comment: No,  i am not parametrizing the curve here but rather to integrate i will substitute only x=sint/cost, and even after that i am getting terms in which i have to integrate sin(cosx) and other terms.  Why don't you do wtihout parametrizing by yourself?  Since everyone knows how to do with parametrizing?

Comment: The above **is** _without_ parametrization... If you're looking for something else or very specific, you should update your question and be more clear.

Comment: what i need to clarify, i have already specified and i think you are unable to understand my problem?  I have break the closed curve into two semi-circles and then integrating using y=√1-x^2. Equation of upper half.  I want to know how i will get same answer since i am unable to do it. Thats what i am simply asking